# Optimizing JOIN on two large tables with additional ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have two tables that are pretty large (first table 5 mio. entries, second one also about that much rows.)
The first table `objects` has a primary key `objectID`
My second table `search` has a column `searchID` and a column `objectID` which references the objectID from the objects table.

What I want to to now is, to get all objects from my objects-table, where the objectIDs are in my search table with searchID = 1
The amount of rows for searchID 1 is pretty large - about two million entries.
I indexed the table with a unique key for searchID/objectID combination.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects
JOIN search
ON search.searchID = 1
AND objects.objectID = search.objectID
```

this query runs pretty fast. **But** only as long as I dont add a `ORDER BY` clause to order by the `name` or the `title` in the objects table.
It seems that any index does not help.
Is this problem unsolvable with an index? What index would I need?

**EDIT:** Table structure as requested

```
TABLE `objects` (
  `objectID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`objectID`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

TABLE `search` (
  `searchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `objectID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `searchID` (`searchID`,`objectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**EXPLAIN** with ORDER BY:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  search      ref     searchID,objectID   searchID    4   const   1014549 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  objects     eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4   db_test.search.objectID     1   Using index
```

**EXPLAIN** without ORDER BY:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys       key         key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  search      ref     searchID,contactID  searchID    4   const   1014549 Using index
1   SIMPLE  contact     eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY 4   db_test.search.objectID     1   Using index
```

Comment: what are the columns and their types in objects table?

Comment: if you want an order by, update your index to (searchID, objectid, orderByColumn)

Comment: @DRapp the orderByColumn is in the  `objects` table

Comment: @Lashane VARCHAR(255)

Comment: @schlimpf one column and its type varchar? can you give whole table structure for objects table

Comment: Show the full table definitions of both tables. Define which column is _"a column"_ you want to `ORDER BY`. Inspect `EXPLAIN` output of the fast and of the slow one. Watch that explain output keeping in mind: [_"if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created."_](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) (your join queue is not necessarily in the order of your query), which for large table may mean writing to the tmp dir on the disk.

Comment: @Lashane added the structure

Comment: @Wrikken Yes I can see it. Without `ORDER BY`, I get `Using index`, with ordering `Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`, but is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Depends on which column you sort, and whether your current query places the table by whose column you want to order first or second. What _is_ the full `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: @Wrikken sorry, added it.

Comment: Ah, makes sense: `search` is first, and the query probably wouldn't perform well the other way around unless `searchID=1` would hit more then 50% of the rows. Bad news: it _will_ require a temporary table. Good news: you _maybe_ can avoid hitting the disk: try to set `tmp_table_size` & `max_heap_table_size` sufficiently high so that temporary table fits in memory (you can temporarily set them higher for your session). If that does not work, or still yields bad results (it _will_ take longer then an unordered query), maybe this is the time for denormalization: add the sort column to `search`.

Comment: In my testenvironment, searchID=1 is hitting about 98% of the rows. But this will not be usually the case. But I assume there is no way to optimize for both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your query is not very correct, proper versions should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects
INNER JOIN search
ON (objects.objectID = search.objectID and search.searchID = 1)
```

another version:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects
where objects.objectID in (
    select search.objectID from search where search.searchID = 1)
```

They are absolutely the same from logic point of view, but I'm not sure that mysql will execute them in the same way, so test both and select fastest one

next issue about indexes:

1. Do you really need to fetch * from table, maybe you can reduce to 1/2 columns?
2. Do you really need varchar(255)? Try to reduce to actual strings length
3. Create index on objects table: INDEXNAME (SORTCOLUMN, objectid, the rest of columns)
4. Change table types to innodb,
5. Increase `sort_buffer_size` and `join_buffer_size`

Now you can change your query to one of these (test both to select fastest)

```
SELECT *
FROM objects use index (INDEXNAME)
INNER JOIN search
ON (objects.objectID = search.objectID and search.searchID = 1)
order by SORTCOLUMN
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM objects use index (INDEXNAME)
where objects.objectID in (
    select search.objectID from search where search.searchID = 1)
order by SORTCOLUMN
```

this is what I'm getting on test db (explain extended is the same for both queries):

```
id  type    table   type    pk  key key_len ref                             rows    filter  Extra
1   SIMPLE  objects index       srtcol  142                                 2091427 100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  search  eq_ref  sid sid     5   const,testhash.objects.objectID 1       100.00  Using index
```

**NOTE:** if you need to have such long strings (varchar 255) - you can make a trick: add integer column, set it value according to proper order and make ordering and index on this column

here is my tables to test:

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
  `objectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sortcol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`objectID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `srtcol` (`sortcol`,`objectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2490316 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `search` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `searchID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `objectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sid` (`searchID`,`objectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2162656 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

each have approximately 2m random rows

Comment: even if i am ordering by the objectID it still uses a temporary table. Can it be that in your testtable you only have entries with searchID = 1?

Comment: `select searchID, count(*) from search
group by searchID` results in: 0 1047788, 1 1049364

Comment: @schlimpf btw, increase sort_buffer_size

Comment: I will need to test this tomorrow, it's 4AM here ;) I cannot reproduce the "using index" at the moment. Maybe after some sleep :)

Comment: Got it! It works, as long as I'm not sorting by objectID and using `INDEX(PRIMARY)`. Weird.

Comment: Interesting. With the subquery, I do not need to hint MySQL to use the corrent index. I leaned that MySQL can optimize JOINs better than subqueries..

Comment: A bit of nitpicking, but the `JOIN` and the `IN()` syntax are not always the same thing! But, in this particular case we seem to be OK indeed.